# Why Do I Get Null Reference Exception When Trying to Get a SQLite Database Connection?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to create a SQLite Dabase but I get an Exception. The error doesn't tell why the exception occurs. It just says a Null Reference Exception.
The Exception Occurs at this line

```
var connection = `DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>().GetConnection();`
```

in the constructor.

here is my .cs file

```
using App4.Persistence;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App4
{

    public class Contact
    {

        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public int  Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength (255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public string ConnectionPath { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>().GetConnection();


        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(ConnectionPath);

            await connection.CreateTableAsync<Contact>();
            var contacts = await connection.Table<Contact>().ToListAsync();
            listViewContacts.ItemsSource = contacts;


            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the interfaith I use for getting the path to the database path by implementing it differently in iOS and Android

```
>     
    > using SQLite;
    > using System;
    > using System.Collections.Generic;
    > using System.Text;
    > 
    > namespace App4.Persistence
    > {
    >     public interface ISQLiteDB
    >     {
    >         SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
    > 
    >     }
    > }
```

and this is the implementation in both iOS and Android.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using App4.Persistence;
using SQLite;

namespace App4.Droid.Persistence
{
   public class SQLiteDB : ISQLiteDB
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var  DatabasePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath,"MySQLite.db3");

            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DatabasePath);

        }

    }
}
```

although the implementation for iOS and Android are the same ( And the interface in this case isn't needed), I will be creating projects for windows requiring different implementation for getting the path to the database.

Any help is appreciated guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the exception was not defining the dependency attrbute in the implementation classes , i should have used `[assembly: Dependency (typeof (SQLiteDB)]` at just above the namespace definition and not in the class.

Although I still get another error when I try to register the implementation classes via the dependency attribute.

I get this error :

> There is no argument that corresponds to the formal parameter
>   "LoadHintArgument" or DependecyAtrrbute.DependencyAttribute(string
>   LoadHint).

Any help on that topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case is a bug only present in Xamarin IOS development, not in Android. It is fixed adding a strange line on "battery" initializing database:

```
        SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init(); // <-- LINE TO ADD
        string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string libFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "Databases");
```